# What English phrase corresponds to the latex command `\rlap`

Tags: documentation, tex-history, english

Using an `alignat` environment, it is possible to write down some notation for a linear program (optimization problem with linear objective function and linear constraints).

What English phrase is a super-sequence of `rlap`?

For example,

> - `pmatrix` is `parentheses matrix`
> - `vmatrix` is `vertical bar matrix`
> - `neq` is `not equal`

What is an English phrase for `rlap`?

[image: a linear program. an optimization problem with linear objective function and linear constraints]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{5}
  \max \quad        & z = &   x_1  & + & 12 x_2  &   &       &         && \\
  \mbox{s.t.} \quad &     & 13 x_1 & + & x_2     & + & 12x_3 & \geq 5  && \tag{constraint 1} \\
                    &     & x_1    &   &         & + & x_3   & \leq 16 && \tag{constraint 2} \\
                    &     & 15 x_1 & + & 201 x_2 &   &       & =    14 && \tag{constraint 3} \\
                    &     & \rlap{x_i \ge 0, i = 1, 2, 3}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `r`ight over`lap`

Comment: Similarly, `\llap` can be thought of as `l`eft over`lap`.

Comment: Incidentally, `\rlap{x_i \ge 0, i = 1, 2, 3}` generates an error message. Change it to `\rlap{$x_i \ge 0$, $i = 1, 2, 3$}`, or load the `mathtools` package and replace `\rlap` with `\mathrlap`.